# qtdesign-UI using PyQt5 is not showing images on raspberry

Tags: image, gui, pi-3b+, lcd

My ui created in qtdesign is not showing the images on raspberry pi 3B+ with LCD-screen. I added them to the ui via the resource and in qtDesign5 they do show up. I have tried to add the image as background for the QDialog, as background-image for the button and as image. And tried jpg, png and bmp files. None of the images are showing. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I am using the ui in my python-script.

```
#This program is a template for using a ui designed in QtDesign5
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages') #That's where PyQt5 is

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Life2Coding(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Life2Coding, self).__init__()
        loadUi('DoorbellUi.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Life2Coding PyQt5 Gui')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.pushButton.cursor()#Dummy function

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=Life2Coding()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My resource-file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="bellimages">
    <file>roundGould.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="bmps">
    <file>beldan.bmp</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And this is my ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>425</width>
    <height>304</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color:rgb(0, 255, 255);
background:url(:/bellimages/roundGould.jpg)</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>110</y>
     <width>401</width>
     <height>111</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Monotype Corsiva</family>
     <pointsize>48</pointsize>
     <italic>true</italic>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="cursor">
    <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/bmps/beldan.bmp);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Ding!Dong!</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="qtScreendesign/qtResource.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: You are probably missing the Qt image plugins. Are you using distro packages or a self built Qt ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! distro packages, I think. I installed QtDesigner5 on my desktop and created this simple ui. It is my first experience with QtDesigner, so I am not even aware that it is possible to build your own Qt. Also I do not know how I can check if the plugin is missing and how I can add it. Can you maybe tell me?
I did have to do "sys.path.append" to get the python-scrit to find the PyQt5 modules. can it be that the qtimage is in another path?

Comment: If you are using raspbian, try installing the qt5-image-formats-plugins package.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the rows of ui file:

```
background:url(:/bellimages/roundGould.jpg)</string>
<string notr="true">background-image: url(:/bmps/beldan.bmp);</string>
```

to:

```
background:url(roundGould.jpg)</string>
<string notr="true">background-image: url(beldan.bmp);</string>
```

Reading the code you posted I think that the .jpg and .bmp files you want to use are in the same folder as the .py file in which you use the loadUi command.
I encountered the same problem in one of my projects and I solved it by editing the file path in the .ui file by deleting :/prefix, indicating only the names of the file.

If you convert your .ui file through the command:

```
pyuic5 DoorbellUi.ui -o DorbellUi.py
```

the lines that refer to your images become:

```
Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(0, 255, 255);\n"
"background:url(:/bellimages/roundGould.jpg)")

self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/bmps/beldan.bmp);")
```

I think the error is in the way the path is specified. Try rewriting the path  file name in .ui file.

Comment: Please try and explain your changes, instead of "change this to make it work". Much better to explain the problem and solution to the user.